# How to combine a column name into MySQL "LIKE" clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to join two tables `t1` and `t2` such that column value in `t2` is `any  valid string including null followed by a value in column of  t table`.

I want something like :

`SELECT * FROM t_cities c JOIN temp_table t ON c.NAME LIKE "%t.token"`but don't know the exact sytax. The above statement gives an error of course.

Comment: You do realize that this join will never use an index and will therefore be a performance nightmare? Rework your database design...

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for here, but it sounds like you've got underlying poor DB design issues that should probably be looked at before trying to work around then with unorthodox  joining techniques.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this query, it should work.

```
SELECT * FROM t_cities as a  
JOIN temp_table as b  
ON a.NAME   LIKE concat("%",b.token);
```

**Note**- This query will not going to be fast as normal join and will take time.

Comment: Thanks,works fine! Performance is not a criteria right now so this will do.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
    SELECT *
  FROM t_cities c
  JOIN temp_table t ON c.field = t.field
 where c.NAME LIKE "%t.token"
```

Comment: Its surely not going to work, giving "%t.token" will use token as hard coded value rather then column value.